# Using Awk, Cut and sed in the same pipe?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, cut

We are doing a Linux workshop for college, and I was looking for a way to demonstrate using awk, sed and cut in the same pipe. I ve been thinking of using them in a apache server context (apache logs file), but is there other contexts I can use awk and sed and cut in?

Comment: Why would you use awk, sed and cut in the same pipe? Awk can do pretty much everything sed and cut can do.

Comment: It is only for demonstration purpose, just to showcase the use of these commands.

Comment: That's kinda like showcasing the use of a screwdriver by hammering in a nail with it. A question like this would be off-topic for this forum anyway though. See [ask]. Having said that, if you want to see an example using a pipeline with awk + **sort** + cut, then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622581/133219

Comment: Thanks for your help. Im not used to asking questions on stack overflow, so I appreciate your input

Comment: For the workshop you might want to demonstrate different ways for extracting a substring, awk OR cut OR sed (or `grep -o` or bash internal functions manipulating a variable or what other solutions you can think of).

Answer (score 1):

here is one use

assume we want to convert <strike>all</strike> some vowels to uppercase sort some words based on the length

given file

```
$ cat file
apple
pear
banana



$ sed 'y/aeiu/AEIU/' file | awk '{print length "\t" $0}' | sort -n | cut -f2

pEAr
ApplE
bAnAnA
```

`sed` can be replaced with `tr` as well.

Comment: I can understand y, but I feel really bad for o.